# I've got this ( Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null ) this error

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I always get this error whenever I try to run it on my computer. Please help me I am stuck. I tried everything that is on the internet in order to resolve this issue, but they all didn't work in my case!**

I was trying to follow a video tutorial which is on javascript I have copied the whole program but the tutor doesn't seem to have any problem with this code, but I am stuck in every project he gives on his channel.

```js
function generateCat() {
  let image = document.getElementById("img");
  let div = document.getElementById("flex-cat-gen");
  image.src = "http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=gif";
  div.appendChild(image);
}
```

```css
.container-2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
  `enter code here`
}

.flex-box-container-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.flex-box-container-2 img {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<title>Cat Generator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container-2">
  <h1>Cat Generator</h1>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="cat-generator" onclick="generateCat()">Generate Cat</button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-box-container-2" id="flex-cat-gen"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no img you are trying to select from the page. How can you choose without creating ?

```
function generateCat() {
  let image = document.createElement("img"); //I created the img element myself.
  let div = document.getElementById("flex-cat-gen");
  image.src = "http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=gif";
  div.appendChild(image);
}
```

or you can choose with id after adding the img tag on your page. you get this error because you choose something that doesn't exist

```js
function generateCat() {
  let image = document.getElementById("img");
  let div = document.getElementById("flex-cat-gen");
  image.src = "http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=gif";
  div.appendChild(image);
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-cat-gen">
  <img src="" alt="" id="img">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="cat-generator" onclick="generateCat()">
  Generate Cat
 </button>
```

Comment: or add an image tag with ID img to the div

Comment: Yep. I was just updating it.

Answer (score 0):

You need EITHER to create an image and append OR have an image and change the src

```js
function generateCat() {
  // change existing src
  let image = document.getElementById("img");
  image.src = "http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=gif";

  // appending new image object
  let div = document.getElementById("flex-cat-gen2");
  let imageObject = document.createElement("img")
  imageObject.src = "http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=gif";
  div.appendChild(imageObject);
}
```

```css
.container-2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
  `enter code here`
}

.flex-box-container-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.flex-box-container-2 img {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<title>Cat Generator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container-2">
  <h1>Cat Generator</h1>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="cat-generator" onclick="generateCat()">Generate Cat</button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-box-container-2" id="flex-cat-gen1">
    <img id="img" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex-box-container-2" id="flex-cat-gen2">
  </div>
</div>
```